# Comments Parent-Child query with indentation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I've been trying to retrieve comments to articles in a pretty common blog fashion way. Here's my sample code:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Sample Table structure for [dbo].[Comments]
-- ----------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Comments] (
[CommentID] int NOT NULL ,
[AddedDate] datetime NOT NULL ,
[AddedBy] nvarchar(256) NOT NULL ,
[ArticleID] int NOT NULL ,
[Body] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL ,
[parentCommentID] int NULL 
)


GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Sample Records of Comments
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body],     [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'1', N'2011-11-26 23:18:07.000', N'user', N'1', N'body', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body],   [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'2', N'2011-11-26 23:18:50.000', N'user', N'2', N'body', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body],    [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'3', N'2011-11-26 23:19:09.000', N'user', N'1', N'body', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body], [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'4', N'2011-11-26 23:19:46.000', N'user', N'3', N'body', null);
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body], [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'5', N'2011-11-26 23:20:16.000', N'user', N'1', N'body', N'1');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body], [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'6', N'2011-11-26 23:20:42.000', N'user', N'1', N'body', N'1');
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Comments] ([CommentID], [AddedDate], [AddedBy], [ArticleID], [Body], [parentCommentID]) VALUES (N'7', N'2011-11-26 23:21:25.000', N'user', N'1', N'body', N'6');
GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Indexes structure for table Comments
-- ----------------------------

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table [dbo].[Comments]
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comments] ADD PRIMARY KEY ([CommentID])
GO

-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Key structure for table [dbo].[Comments]
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comments] ADD FOREIGN KEY ([parentCommentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].   [Comments] ([CommentID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
GO
```

I thought I could use a CTE query to do the job like this:

```
WITH CommentsCTE(CommentID, AddedDate, AddedBy, ArticleID, Body, parentCommentID, lvl,  sortcol)
AS
(
SELECT CommentID, AddedDate, AddedBy, ArticleID, Body, parentCommentID, 0,   cast(CommentID as varbinary(max))
FROM Comments
UNION ALL
SELECT P.CommentID, P.AddedDate, P.AddedBy, P.ArticleID, P.Body, P.parentCommentID,    PP.lvl+1,
CAST(sortcol + CAST(P.CommentID AS BINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(max))
FROM Comments AS P
JOIN CommentsCTE AS PP
ON P.parentCommentID = PP.CommentID
)
SELECT
REPLICATE('--', lvl)
+ right('>',lvl)+ AddedBy
+ ' :: '
+ Body,
CommentID,
parentCommentID,
lvl
FROM CommentsCTE
WHERE ArticleID = 1
order by sortcol
go
```

but the results have been very disappointing so far, and after days of tweaking I decided to ask for help. I was looking for a method to display hierarchical comments to articles like it happens in blogs.

[edit]
The problem with this query is that I get duplicates because I couldn't figure out how to  properly select the ArticleID which I want comments from to display. I'm also looking for  a method that sorts children entries by date within a same level.
An example of what I'm trying to accomplish could be something like:

```
(ArticleID[post retrieved])
-------------------------
-------------------------
(Comments[related to the article id above])
first comment[no parent]
--[first child to first comment]
--[second child to first comment]
----[first child to second child comment to first comment]
--[third child to first comment]
----[first child to third child comment to first comment]
------[(recursive child): first child to first child to third child comment to first comment]
------[(recursive child): second child to first child to third child comment to first comment]
second comment[no parent]
third comment[no parent]
--[first child to third comment]
```

I kinda got myself lost in all this mess...I appreciate any help or simpler ways to get this working. Thanks

Comment: Disappointing how?  How are your current results different from what you were looking to get?

Comment: well, from that query I get duplicates that weren't supposed to be there and couldn't figure out how to order comments by date in proper way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close.  I've made two modifications to your recursive query:

```
WITH CommentsCTE (CommentID, AddedDate, AddedBy, ArticleID, Body, parentCommentID, lvl, Thread)
AS
(
    SELECT  CommentID, 
            AddedDate, 
            AddedBy, 
            ArticleID, 
            Body, 
            parentCommentID, 
            0,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CommentID) as Thread
    FROM @Comments
    where parentCommentID is null
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT  P.CommentID, 
            P.AddedDate, 
            P.AddedBy, 
            P.ArticleID, 
            P.Body, 
            P.parentCommentID,    
            PP.lvl+1,
            PP.Thread
    FROM @Comments AS P
    JOIN CommentsCTE AS PP ON P.parentCommentID = PP.CommentID
)
SELECT  REPLICATE('--', lvl) + right('>',lvl)+ AddedBy + ' :: ' + Body,
        CommentID,
        parentCommentID,
        lvl,
        AddedDate,
        Thread
FROM CommentsCTE
WHERE ArticleID = 1
order by Thread, CommentID
```

First, adding

```
where parentCommentID is null
```

to your anchor query eliminates your duplicates.  Second, to sort them properly, you need a Thread identifier.  I added a row number to your anchor query to create the thread number.  That allows you to sort the results properly.

[Here is an example of it in action.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119351/)

Comment: Many, many many thanks. It seems exactly what I've been looking for. It will be tested extensively and I may report more feedbacks in future.